# How can I handle Geo Location popup in browser using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to share my location on click of 'Share Location' button on the popup. How can I handle this using selenium webdriver? Refer image below.

Steps to reach to Location popup:

1. Navigate to [this URL](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation)
2. Click on `Try it` button from right section
3. Location popup will be displayed as :

   [image: https]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable geolocation support in chromedriver for Selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411816/how-do-i-enable-geolocation-support-in-chromedriver-for-selenium)

Comment: you want to remove this popup?

Comment: @SaurabhGaur: I am Currently working on e-commerce project and any user is logged in,  it is mandatory to check the current location. That is why I need to handle this popup? So, how can I click on 'Share Location' button in popup?

Comment: @SameerD this can not be possible by selenium to click on `Share Location` button, you need to create custom profile with allow share location, [have a look on this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390611/how-can-i-allow-location-access-using-selenium) for for information

Comment: @pArAs: I want to remove this popup, but using selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 11):

So lets say if for launching any site, this `GeoLocation` pop up comes, You can't interact with this element as its not a `WebElement`, so you have to handle it before the browser launches a site so below are the properties you need to set to launch the browser:-

**For Firefox:**

```
FirefoxProfile geoDisabled = new FirefoxProfile();
geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.enabled", false);
geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.provider.use_corelocation", false);
geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing", false);
geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing.allow", false);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, geoDisabled);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

**For Chrome:**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("enable-strict-powerful-feature-restrictions");
options.addArguments("disable-geolocation");
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
cap = cap.merge(DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Need to add capabilities as argument of FirefoxDriver instance.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find this anywhere!

Comment: I can't find any good documentation on how to do this in NodeJS. Also, I'm looking for how to handle the notification permission (not geolocation)

Answer (score 1):

```
    FirefoxProfile geoDisabled = new FirefoxProfile();
    geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.enabled", false);
    geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.provider.use_corelocation", false);
    geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing", false);
    geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing.allow", false);
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, geoDisabled);

    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("Driver_Name", "Driver_path");
    driver =new FirefoxDriver(geoDisabled);
```

Need to pass the instance of FirefoxProfile.