# Get geolocation from webpage by scraping using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I try to scrape this [page](https://www.coordonnees-gps.fr/) :

The goal is to **collect the latitude and the longitude**. However I see that *the HTML content don't change* after any submit in "Adresse" case, and I don't know if this is the problem of my "empty list".

My script :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.coordonnees-gps.fr/"

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\jbourbon\Desktop\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "col-md-9"})

latitude = []
longitude = []

for item in g_data:
    latitude.append(item.contents[0].findAll("input", {"id": "latitude"}))
    longitude.append(item.contents[0].findAll("input", {"id": "longitude"}))

print(latitude)
print(longitude)
```

And here, what I have with my [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msqPe.png)

Ty :)

Comment: Why did you mark your question with `Selenium` tag? Did you try the same with `Selenium`? If so, add this code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you're doing, the problem is that when you open the link using `selenium` or `requests` the geolocation is not available instantly, it's available after few seconds **(`aaf9ec0.js` adds it to the html dynamically, so request won't work anyway)**, also seems like `input#latitude` is also not giving the values, you can get it from `div#info_window`.

I've modified the code a bit, it should get you the `lat, long`, works for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re

url = "https://www.coordonnees-gps.fr/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2) # wait for geo location to become ready

# no need to fetch it again using requests, we've already done it using selenium above
#r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"id": "info_window"})[0]
#extract latitude, longitutde
latitude, longitude = re.findall(r'Latitude :</strong> ([\.\d]*) \| <strong>Longitude :</strong> ([\.\d]*)<br/>', str(g_data))[0]
print(latitude)
print(longitude)
```

**Output**

```
25.594095
85.137565
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you have to enable GeoLocation for the chromedriver instance. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767551/how-can-i-handle-geo-location-popup-in-browser-using-selenium-webdriver) for a lead on how to do that.