# How to check if an alert is present on a page with JavaScript or Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am making a bot, and this bot is searching constantly but some times when it searches, an alert appears asking the user for access to their location. How do i check if this alert is present or better yet disable it?

So far i have tried to disable stuff through about:config:

```
    var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences- 
       service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);

    prefs.setIntPref("network.cookie.cookieBehavior",  4);

    prefs.setBoolPref("privacy.donottrackheader.enabled", true); 

    prefs.setIntPref("permissions.default.geo", 2);
```

But alerts still pop up. I also tried making a new firefox profile with pre installed add-ons just to block dialog boxes and pop ups, but it still gives me dialog boxes.

I really am stumped this time. If you know how i can check if a page is alerting something with JS or Selenium python then please tell me cause at this point, that would help me a lot. If you know how to disable javascript alerts then that would be awesome.

Comment: This might help, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767551/how-can-i-handle-geo-location-popup-in-browser-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @David it is actually an alert not a pop-up. If it was a pop up my add-ons would have blocked it.

Comment: Are you using chrome and firefox?

Comment: @PritamMaske Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable alerts with:

```
window.alert = () => false
```

from python that's:

```
driver.execute_script("window.alert = () => false")
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume one is present on the exception of a non located element within a try/catch block, then try to use

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

to proceed with the entended behavior :)

Answer (score 2):

**Use :**

```
prefs.setIntPref("permissions.default.desktop-notification",  1);
```