# How to handle pop up browser ? (using Robot Framework,python)

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using Robot IDE for creating robot automation test scripts.

For my test the browser is asking for permission to show notification. Since it's a web-based alert dialog I'm not able to access it in my robot script. If I am clicking on the "Allow" button manually then it proceeds to the test and passes successfully. I need to allow the browser to show notification with my robot script.[image]

As you can see from the image I want to click on the Allow button which is necessary to go ahead in my test.

So can anyone know how can I click on the "Allow" button of the browser confirmation popup via the robot test script?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Also, make sure to add some code and show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could just allow or block all the notifications, in this way no pop up will appear

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can disable them using `DesiredCapabilities`. In this geolocation case, you should use `disable-geolocation` option.

Here's an example: [How can I handle Geo Location popup in browser using selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767551/how-can-i-handle-geo-location-popup-in-browser-using-selenium-webdriver)